# How to handle 'Object': ambiguous symbol in Visual Studio

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, ambiguous

I am creating a C++/CLI wrapper for native C code that has it's own `Object` typedef and am receiving the `C2872 'Object': ambiguous symbol` error when linking. The compiler output is:

```
1>C:\src\OS_kernel.h(27): error C2872: 'Object': ambiguous symbol 
1>C:\src\OS_types.h(261): note: could be 'ObjectStruct *Object' 
1>C:\src\OS_kernel.h(27): note: or       'System::Object'
```

It may be worth mentioning that I am mocking this native C code for the purposes of the C++/CLI wrapper; not sure if that opens up a potential solution that would otherwise not be available if no source code was available. I'm guessing there is a way to specify which definition I want the code to use, but I don't know how to specify that. Is that possible? I want to specify it to use the `ObjectStruct *Object`.

It would be great if I didn't have to modify the mock code since it could potentially be hundreds or thousands of individual places.

As an aside, I am also receiving this error for other types the native library is using, such as `Buffer` and `Boolean`.

Comment: You should be able to use `::Object` with the scope resolution operator `::` to refer to the global scope C `Object`.

Comment: That worked! Sadly, this solution means I need to touch every place this ambiguous error occurs in the mock code though.

Answer (score 3):

OK, since you're getting the error in OS_kernel.h, I'm guessing that's part of the C code you're wrapping.

Obviously, one possible solution is to treat the name `Object` as a reserved word, and edit your C code to not use it. One could argue that this is the most correct solution, but it may not be possible to do that.

Depending on how you're referencing the C code, it may be reasonable to compile it as C++, and stick it entirely within a namespace. That way, when the C code (now C++ code) uses `Object` it will see the typedef within its namespace, and you'll have the option to reference either namespace in your code.

The fact that you're getting this error from your library's header file indicates to me that you've got a `using namespace System;` directive, and that the `#include` of your library's header files comes *after* that using directive. Consider removing the `using namespace System;`, or at least moving it after the `#include`. This way, you won't get that error in the library's headers, you'll just have to deal with it in your code.

Comment: Ahh, good suggestion for removing the `using namespace System;`. Thanks!